# sails generate [something] error

Tags: node.js, npm, sails.js

Is there a difference between

```
sails generate user?
```

and

```
sails generate api user?
```

If there is, I'm getting an error when using the first command, getting this result:

```
error: No generator called `user` found; perhaps you meant `sails generate api user`?
```

I was wondering if the recent versions of sails has changed their blueprint generate, but couldn't find anything on their documentation and this didn't seem too common of a problem.

I have done a complete removal of npm, node.js, and sails and did a fresh install and am still getting this problem.

I am using ubuntu, and when doing npm ls I got the following:

```
npm ERR! missing: grunt@~0.4.0, required by grunt-contrib-jst@0.6.0
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sails generate user
```

That is now

```
sails generate api <foo>
```

Here are some more generate commands:

```
sails generate model <foo> [attribute1:type1, attribute2:type2 ... ]
sails generate controller <foo> [action1, action2, ...]
sails generate adapter <foo>
sails generate generator <foo>
```

For more on generate, read the documentation:

[Sails generate documentation](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/cli/sailsgenerate.html)